# Question about the Field of Automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $L$ be a field and $\alpha $ is an automorphism of $L$. Given is the Set

$F=\left\{ l\in L:\alpha (l)=l \right\} $

I showed that $F$ is a Subfield of $L$. I want to conclude further that if $\mathbb{Q}\le L$ every automorphism of L is a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism.
How do I have to argue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbb{Q}\subset L$, and let $f$ be  an autumorphism, $f(1)=1$ implies $f(n)=n$ since $f$ is linear, this implies $f(n{1\over n})=f(n)f({1\over n})=1$ implies $f({1\over n})={1\over n}$ implies $f({p\over q})=f(p)f({1\over q})={p\over q}$